# Write a JavaScript program that accept two integers and display the larger.

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, control-flow

I figured out a few ways to write the above function. However, I feel like I am both doing it in wrong order, and that I have too many conditions in each line...

Can this be done in a simpler way (say, to only run the function IF the number is an integer), and then compare the numbers, instead of me checking if they're integers in each line.

I understand there are many ways to write this, would appreciate staying in the same if - else method, but a shorter, simpler version, and probably a better flow.

```
function integer(a,b) {

  if (a > 0 && b > 0 && a > b) {
    document.write("The larger number is " + a );
  } else if (a > 0 && b > 0 && a < b) {
    document.write("The larger number is " + b);
  } else if (a === b && a > 0 && b > 0) {
    document.write("Both numbers are equal!")
  } else {
      document.write("Please add an integer!");

  }
}

integer(-1,-1);
```

Comment: Do they have to be positive?  You're doing a lot of `> 0` checks but that's not mentioned in the question.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Comment: I assume this is without `Math.max`?   If so -> `return a > b ? a : b;`

Comment: Validate the input first. Then if valid compare them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the whole numbers are integers(i.e. positive(1), negative(-1) and zero). Fractions and decimals are not integers.

```
function integer(a,b) {

    var isInteger = Number.isInteger(a) && Number.isInteger(b);

    if(isInteger && a === b)
        document.write("Both numbers are equal!");

    else if(isInteger)
        document.write("The larger number is " + Math.max(a,b));

    else
        document.write("Please add an integer!");

}

integer(-1,-1);
```

Note : If you don't want negative numbers and zero as integer, please use (a > 0 && b > 0) instead of (Number.isInteger(a) && Number.isInteger(b))

Comment: Yes, I realized that know. I don't know why I was assuming they all have to be positive. 
Anyway, if they did have to be - now I know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have to check for `>0`? You use the function with params `-1,-1`.
Anyway you can do something like:

```
function integer(a,b) {

if(typeof a !== 'number' || typeof b!== 'number' ) {
    document.write("Please add 2 valid numbers");
} else {
  if(a==b) {
    document.write("Two equals number");
   }  else {
    document.write("The larger number is " + (a > b ? a : b ));
   }

  }
}
integer(-1,-1);
```

Or the same function but using only ternary operators. More compact but kind of unreadable.
If you are doing your homework this is the kind of stuff your teacher would like :) (but I discourage to use it in real world)

```
function integer(a,b) {
    (typeof a !== 'number' || typeof b!== 'number' ) ?
        document.write("Please add 2 valid numbers") :
        a == b ? document.write("Two equals number") :
        document.write("The larger number is " + (a > b ? a : b ));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function integer(a,b) {
    if(a>=0 && b>=0)
    {
        if(a!=b)
        {
            document.write("The larger number is " + Math.max(a,b));
        }
        else
        {
            document.write("Both numbers are equal!")
        }
    } else {
        document.write("Please add an integer!");
    }
}

integer(-1,-1);
```